# Which is best in this scenario, Base64 or static images?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Part of my application Makes heavy use of image manipulation. Cropping, filters etc. using ajax posts and image processing server side using a variety of methods. Every manipulation action that the user takes creates a physical image without deleting the original in order to allow an 'undo' system  giving the user the ability to revert his image back to any previous point in time.

All these 'temporary' images are removed via a post to the server when a user finishes their session or closes their browser.

For modern browsers we will be extending the image manipulation capabilities using html5. Using canvas gives us the ability to perform all of these image manipulations client side without ever creating additional static images by encoding and dynamically embedding base64 data.

My concern is the 'undo' system. With the static fallback method we store store an array of objects which contains the links to the static images. This gives the complete undo functionality. However if we do this all clientside then this array will have to actually contain copies of the base64 data for each 'undo' point For each image that the user is manipulating (a typical use case might be 20 original images each with 4-5 undo points).

Before I spend a couple of days prototyping this I was hoping someone might have some comments regarding this method. Is it a good idea? Bad idea? Is storing a huge data object of base64 images a bad idea from a browser performance and memory usage perspective?

Any thought are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is storing a huge data object of base64 images a bad idea from a browser performance and memory usage perspective?` how big do you expect them to be? 1400px on a side, yes, 5px on a side, no. Also, how do you know when they close their browser?

Comment: They could be anything up to 1200px square.  We are using the javascript onbeforeunload event which fires when a user closes their browser and sends a post to the server containg the image filenames.  It works wonderfully.  The only time the images don't get deleted is if a browser crashes.  But we have clean up methods set to automatically occur after a given time anyway.

Comment: I think this idea is fine. Copying my math from below: If each image is ~1200px (so 1.2 kilopixels or .0012 megapixels) then we can assume each picture is ~24kb, so if we add 30% on top of that, that's ~30k per image. 20 images times 5 backup points is 100 points, times 30k images, is 3MB. I've got larger audiofiles on my computer, of course. I think that storing stuff like this in localstorage on the local machine is perfectly cromulent.

Comment: Actually, as I read it, the images can be 1200px square (1200px would be 300px x 400 px). This is 1200*1200px = 1,440,000 pixels, which means 5,760,000 bytes or 5.5 MB of uncompressed data in four channels (RGBa), or 7.15 MB in base-64 encoding.

Comment: Ouch... i clearly need to do some math of my own looking at typical use case scenarios. Images are jpeg, and tend to average about the 200kb mark for a higher quality one.  Would I be right then in thinking that a base64 represenation of that would be much much more?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea. Base64 takes 30% more storage that the actual data encoded. If your on-server images are accessible via actual URLs, consider keeping references to `<img>` elements detached from the DOM.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a terrible idea. If each image is ~1200px (so 1.2 kilopixels or .0012 megapixels) then we can assume each picture is ~24kb, so if we add 30% on top of that, that's ~30k per image. 20 images times 5 backup points is 100 points, times 30k images, is 3MB. I've got larger audiofiles on my computer, of course.

Comment: The other alternative would be to perform all manipulations client side, and post the base64 data back to the server to generate actual images?  Does this feel like the best compromise?

Comment: True, not a terrible idea, but it makes no sense to keep B64 data if you do not actually need it in B64 form. Depends on the actual code that would need those images anyway.

Comment: The point of it would be to keep any actual image files from ever appearing on the server disk, reducing storage requirements and disk access needs etc.

Comment: @gordyr I believe with `<canvas>` you can actually keep the raw image data as returned by [`canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Comment: that data should be roughly equivalent (ok, 30% smaller?) of what we were already discussing

Comment: how would the raw data retrieved via .getImageData compare with the filesize of an equivalent jpeg?

Comment: Actually it might be larger due to lack of compression. Disregard that suggestion.